# Has anyone actually been able to load a model exported from three.js editor?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to prefaces this by stating that I am not a programmer however I am a designer and 3D artist who likes to dabble in code every-once-in-a-while. My basic question is if anyone has had any luck loading in a model from the [three.js](https://threejs.org/editor/) editor  into a actual web page. I have tried running a server and I also uploaded to a server as I am aware of the browser security issue.

Here are a few things that I've tried:

1. I tried to use `blender` to export my models but was unable to get them to show up in any browser.
2. I then was able to export a collada file and import it into the three.js editor. I adjusted a few materials, added an environment map and exported with all three different export options (geometry, object, and scene).
3. I've even tried exporting primitives from the three.js editor with no luck either.
4. I've tried all three exports with code I found on an internet demo that seems to do the same thing I'm trying to do where I tried to replace their model with my model (yes, I'm not a programmer but I like to try things...)
5. I will post the code I have below
6. I did try both `THREE.ObjectLoader()` and `THREE.JSONLoader()`.

***I am not the author of this code and I do not claim to be.***

```
    <script>
      var scene, camera, renderer;
      var WIDTH  = window.innerWidth;
      var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
      var SPEED = 0.01;

    function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        initMesh();
        initCamera();
        initLights();
        initRenderer();
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    }

    function initCamera() {
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10);
      camera.position.set(0, 3.5, 5);
      camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    }


    function initRenderer() {
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
      renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    function initLights() {
      var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
      scene.add(light);
    }

      var mesh = null;
    function initMesh() {
      var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
      loader.load('models/cubegeo.json', function(geometry, materials) {
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
        mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 0.75;
        mesh.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
        scene.add(mesh);
      });
    }

    function rotateMesh() {
      if (!mesh) {
        return;
      }
      mesh.rotation.x -= SPEED * 2;
      mesh.rotation.y -= SPEED;
      mesh.rotation.z -= SPEED * 3;
    }

    function render() {
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      rotateMesh();
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    init();
    render();

    </script>
```

One of the models that I'm trying to load seems fairly simple and I created it and downloaded from the `three.js` editor as GEOMETRY.

```
    {
        "metadata": {
            "version": 4.5,
            "type": "BufferGeometry",
            "generator": "BufferGeometry.toJSON"
        },
        "uuid": "8A2042A8-9DE2-42F5-A970-56E64669E516",
        "type": "BoxBufferGeometry",
        "width": 7,
        "height": 7,
        "depth": 7,
        "widthSegments": 1,
        "heightSegments": 1,
        "depthSegments": 1
    }
```

Below is the same cube but downloaded from the `Three.js` editor as an Object:

```
    {
        "metadata": {
            "version": 4.5,
            "type": "Object",
            "generator": "Object3D.toJSON"
        },
        "geometries": [
            {
                "uuid": "8A2042A8-9DE2-42F5-A970-56E64669E516",
                "type": "BoxBufferGeometry",
                "width": 7,
                "height": 7,
                "depth": 7,
                "widthSegments": 1,
                "heightSegments": 1,
                "depthSegments": 1
            }],
        "materials": [
            {
                "uuid": "2455ACBD-6ECC-4B17-867B-9C971D647F91",
                "type": "MeshStandardMaterial",
                "color": 16777215,
                "roughness": 0,
                "metalness": 0,
                "emissive": 9308169,
                "depthFunc": 3,
                "depthTest": true,
                "depthWrite": true
            }],
        "object": {
            "uuid": "CA57782F-5DB8-484F-B3A0-AD27862CE114",
            "type": "Mesh",
            "name": "Box",
            "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
            "geometry": "8A2042A8-9DE2-42F5-A970-56E64669E516",
            "material": "2455ACBD-6ECC-4B17-867B-9C971D647F91"
        }
    }
```

When I use `THREE.JSONLoader()` with the GEOMETRY cube I get the following error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        at parseModel (three.js:36833)
        at JSONLoader.parse (three.js:37241)
        at Object.onLoad (three.js:36764)
        at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.js:31352)
```

When I use `ObjectLoader()` with the Object cube I get the following error:

```
    THREE.MeshFaceMaterial has been removed. Use an Array instead.
    MeshFaceMaterial @ three.js:44719
    three.js:46378 THREE.GeometryUtils: .center() has been moved to Geometry. Use geometry.center() instead.
    center @ three.js:46378
    three.js:46379 Uncaught TypeError: geometry.center is not a function
        at Object.center (three.js:46379)
        at (index):53
        at ObjectLoader.parse (three.js:37362)
        at Object.onLoad (three.js:37318)
        at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.js:31352)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running the THREE Editor and THREE.js library from the same version. If you're running the latest version of both, try downgrading to an earlier version of THREE.js perhaps .70. If this doesn't work, check back.. the THREEjs object save routines may have gotten out of sync with the most recent builds.. and we'll either need to file a bug report, or figure out the most recent version that still works, to get you up and running. But yes, I have gotten it to work in the past...